# How do I add a list of custom components to an element dynamically in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm relatively new to Vue so please bear with me.  I'm trying to add a child component dynamically however I'm hitting a bit of a brick wall at the moment.

I currently have the following in **Home.vue**:

```
<script setup>
   import SearchResultItem from '../components/SearchResultItem.vue'; // my child component
</script>

<template>
   <div id="searchResults">
      <SearchResultItem value="Search result 1"/>
      <SearchResultItem value="Search result 2"/>
   </div>
</template>
```

My child component (**SearchResultItem.vue**) is defined as:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['value'],
        name: "SearchResultItem"
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div>{{value}}</div> 
</template>
```

The above works as expected when I load the page.  I can see that Vue has rendered the page with the values I pass to the child component.  All good.

I now want to add the SearchResultItem child component dynamically using Javascript within the  tag however I'm not sure how I go about it.

I have tried the following:

```
<script setup>
   const searchResults = ref([]);

   onMounted(() => {
    searchResults.value.push({type: SearchResultItem});
    searchResults.value.push({type: SearchResultItem});
  });
</script>

<template>
   <div id="searchResults" v-for="searchResult in searchResults">
      {{ searchResults }}
   </div>
</template>
```

however it's not adding the child component as expected.  It appears to be adding the object as a string to the binded {{ searchResults}} and displaying it as text instead.

I have a work around which manipulates the DOM directly like the following:

```
const elem = document.getElementById("searchResults");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Search result 1"));
elem.appendChild(div)
```

however from what I've read, the recommended way when working with Vue is to manipulate / bind the underlying data.

So how would I add my child component dynamically in Vue by working with the underlying data.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think dynamic components are what you are looking for.
You might take a look at the documentation:

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components

```js
<script setup>
   const searchResults = ref([]);

   onMounted(() => {
    searchResults.value.push({type: SearchResultItem});
    searchResults.value.push({type: SearchResultItem});
  });
</script>

<template>
   <div id="searchResults">
       <component v-for="searchResult in searchResults" :is="searchResult.type"></component>
   </div>
</template>
```